# Loop Through and Remove Values Row By Row on Matching Sum

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've a table that has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE HRD.SAMPLE_TEST_2020
(
  ID         VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
  STOREDATE  DATE,
  VALUE      NUMBER,
  INFO       VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
)
```

**Sample Data** - Below are the sample data

```
ID      STOREDATE       VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2   DONE
1122    1/2/2020    4   DONE
1122    1/3/2020    8   DONE
1122    1/4/2020    10  DONE
```

The requirement is to delete or remove data that has matching sum of 8. Say id 1122 has value
of total 24 and I've to remove 8 out of it. So total remaining would be 16. So final output would be:

```
ID      STOREDATE       VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2   DONE
1122    1/2/2020    4   DONE
1122    1/3/2020    0   
1122    1/4/2020    10  DONE
```

This may have different scenario say the following:

```
ID      STOREDATE       VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    1   DONE
1122    1/2/2020    7   DONE
1122    1/3/2020    13  DONE
1122    1/4/2020    19  DONE
```

**Output**:

```
ID      STOREDATE       VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    0   
1122    1/2/2020    0   
1122    1/3/2020    13  DONE
1122    1/4/2020    19  DONE
```

I am not sure in what approach this should be done and tried a simple one that actually
doesn't have much impact. Here is the tried one and if this could be improved in any way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure ADJUST_VALUE
AS

TotalValue number;

cursor sample_cursor is

SELECT M.EMPNO, SUM(M.VALUE) TOTAL FROM SAMPLE_TEST_2020 m GROUP BY M.EMPNO HAVING SUM(M.VALUE) >= 8;

sample sample_cursor%ROWTYPE;

begin 
open sample_cursor;
  LOOP

     FETCH sample_cursor into sample;
       EXIT WHEN sample_cursor%NOTFOUND;

       TotalValue := sample.TOTAL - 8;
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TotalValue);

       UPDATE SAMPLE_TEST_2020 m SET M.VALUE = 0, M.INFO = NULL;

  END LOOP;

close sample_cursor;         
end;
```

I am open to any approach regarding the procedure using Microsoft SQL Server or Oracle.

Comment: Why tag SQL Server and Oracle, and why tag versions for both that are **completely** unsupported? Please only tag the RDBMS you are using and the relevant version.  SQL Server and Oracle are very different and both of these versions are very old (released in 2008 and 2005 respectively).

Comment: Also looping, regardless of the RDBMS, is something you want to avoid. RDBMS excel at set based tasks, not iterative ones.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using the old versions and you can say it's one of kind practice for me. You can provide me any idea using any version but at least that support the versions I am using @Larnu.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about the logic? if current row value is 8 or SUM of Current row and Prev row is 8 OR some other logic?

Comment: If you have time, please see this @mkRabbani - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60905844/query-result-not-returned-as-expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I consider your database is MSSQL server version 2012 or newer, you can use LEAD and LAG function as below to achieve your requirement.

Logic: (guess from your sample output)

1. If current row value is 8 then 0
2. If current row value + previous row value is 8 then 0
3. If current row value + next row value is 8 then 0

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=93a3da6a5e9816f30d1f843aa3b6c5f1)

Query is-

```
SELECT ID,
STOREDATE,
CASE 
    WHEN VALUE = 8 THEN 0
    WHEN VALUE + LAG(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY STOREDATE) = 8 THEN 0
    WHEN VALUE + LEAD(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY STOREDATE) = 8 THEN 0
    ELSE VALUE
END VALUE,
INFO
FROM your_table
```

If I understand correct from your below comment, you wants just one first record where above logic match to be converted to 0. Once one record converted to 0, no other row will be converted to 0 whatever the logic matched or not. If it is correct, the following logic should work for you and VALUE3 will be your final column.

[DEMO2 HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c09c824d12621bb5cb8a24a33b7a1b88)

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,
    STOREDATE,
    VALUE,
    CASE 
        WHEN VALUE = 8 THEN 0
        WHEN VALUE + LAG(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY STOREDATE) = 8 THEN 0
        WHEN VALUE + LEAD(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY STOREDATE) = 8 THEN 0
        ELSE VALUE
    END VALUE2,
    INFO
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT *,
CASE 
    WHEN 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE A 
            WHERE A.VALUE2 = 0 AND A.STOREDATE < B.STOREDATE
        ) >= 1 AND B.VALUE > 7 THEN B.VALUE
    ELSE B.VALUE2
END VALUE3
FROM CTE B
```

Comment: This works like a charm @mkRabbani. Though I would request one thing if it could be done. Say if I get sum of **8** or a value of 8 at the beginning, then it shouldn't check for the next sum of 8. Or if doesn't get sum of **8** or a value of **8** at the beginning, then it should check for the next values that matches the sum. In the same time, I would like to update those rows that matches the sum. Is it possible in the procedure?

Comment: Applying subquery on the above query, your requirement might be possible to achive. I will give a try tomorrow.

Comment: Hi @user8512043, I have edited my answer. Please check newly added script meet your requirement or not.

Comment: It worked @mkRabbani but it should also update the value **7** as 0, because sum of 1 and 7 returns 8,

Comment: For 1 and 7, it should stop at 7. That means 1 and 7 will have 0 respectively.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210367/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-user8512043).