# Query Result Not Returned As Expected

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle10g

I am struggling with a query that tried few days back with a suggestion of one of **SO** user and got it work with the following:

```
WITH your_table(ID,STOREDATE,VALUE,INFO)
AS
(
SELECT 1122,'1/1/2020',2,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,'1/2/2020',1,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,'1/3/2020',7,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,'1/4/2020',8,'DONE'
),

CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,
    STOREDATE,
    VALUE,
    CASE 
        WHEN VALUE = 8 THEN 0
        WHEN VALUE + LAG(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY STOREDATE) = 8 THEN 0
        WHEN VALUE + LEAD(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY STOREDATE) = 8 THEN 0
        ELSE VALUE
    END VALUE2,
    INFO
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT *,
CASE 
    WHEN 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE A 
            WHERE A.VALUE2 = 0 AND A.STOREDATE < B.STOREDATE
        ) >= 1 AND B.VALUE = 8 THEN B.VALUE
    ELSE B.VALUE2
END VALUE3
FROM CTE B
```

**N.B**: My idea was to get the summation of 8 at any given row. So for the above input, my expected output is this.

**Output**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/2/2020    0           //1 + 7 = 8; it'll update both the rows with zero
1122    1/3/2020    0           //For this, it's just fine
1122    1/4/2020    8       DONE
```

Now my problem is with the below inputs that I can't figure out how to get expected result set.

**Input**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/2/2020    1       DONE
1122    1/3/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/4/2020    7       DONE
```

**Expected Output**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/2/2020    0       
1122    1/3/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/4/2020    0
```

**Input**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/2/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/3/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/4/2020    2       DONE
```

**Expected Output**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    0       
1122    1/2/2020    0       
1122    1/3/2020    0       
1122    1/4/2020    0
```

I may have several ids to get the exact result as below but making tweaks to the query doesn't get me to what I wanted. Any suggestion would be appreciated - Thanks.

```
WITH your_table(ID,STOREDATE,VALUE,INFO)
AS
(
SELECT 1122,'1/1/2020',2,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,'1/2/2020',7,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,'1/3/2020',1,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,'1/4/2020',8,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 4466,'1/1/2020',2,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 4466,'1/2/2020',7,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 4466,'1/3/2020',1,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 4466,'1/4/2020',8,'DONE'
),

CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,
    STOREDATE,
    VALUE,
    CASE 
        WHEN VALUE = 8 THEN 0
        WHEN VALUE + LAG(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY STOREDATE) = 8 THEN 0
        WHEN VALUE + LEAD(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY STOREDATE) = 8 THEN 0
        ELSE VALUE
    END VALUE2,
    INFO
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT *,
CASE 
    WHEN 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE A 
            WHERE A.VALUE2 = 0 AND A.STOREDATE < B.STOREDATE
        ) >= 1 AND B.VALUE = 8 THEN B.VALUE
    ELSE B.VALUE2
END VALUE3
FROM CTE B
```

**Expected Output**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/2/2020    0           
1122    1/3/2020    0           
1122    1/4/2020    8       DONE
4466    1/1/2020    2       DONE
4466    1/2/2020    0           
4466    1/3/2020    0           
4466    1/4/2020    8       DONE
```

**Update 1**: Please check the below

**Input**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/2/2020    1       DONE
1122    1/3/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/4/2020    7       DONE
```

**Expected Output**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/2/2020    0       
1122    1/3/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/4/2020    0
```

**Input**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/2/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/3/2020    2       DONE
1122    1/4/2020    2       DONE
```

**Expected Output**:

```
ID      STOREDATE   VALUE   INFO
1122    1/1/2020    0       
1122    1/2/2020    0       
1122    1/3/2020    0       
1122    1/4/2020    0
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first big mistake is that 'stordate' is not a date, but a character string representation of a date. Thus, all comparisons will be comparisons of a string, not a date.  As a string, which comes first, '01/02/2020' or '02/01/2019'.

```
WITH your_table(ID,STOREDATE,VALUE,INFO)
AS
(
SELECT 1122,to_date('01/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),2,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,to_date('01/02/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),1,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,to_date('01/03/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),7,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,to_date('01/04/2020','dd/mm/yyyy'),8,'DONE'
),
```

Comment: AFAIK, `TO_DATE` is a built-in function for oracle and the above sample is used for **SQL Server** @EdStevens.

Comment: @user8512043.  The thread is tagged both oracle and sqlserver.  That, in itself, is  a mistake on the part  of the OP becasue, as we all know, solutions are seldom if ever 'database agnostic'.  The very first code sample in the opening question looks like oracle sql to me.  In any event, the basic principle still holds -- it's treating a character string as if it were a date and as such, comparisons will not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please check this bellow solution-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d5f2fdf0b7a212e1e4be4e82c5d05646)

[DEMO2 HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6319b64521ed9bb6926b3708dd7ac082)

```
WITH your_table(ID,STOREDATE,VALUE,INFO)
AS
(
SELECT 1122,'1/1/2020',2,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 1122,'1/2/2020',7,'DONE' UNION ALL -- This two returns zero
SELECT 1122,'1/3/2020',1,'DONE' UNION ALL -- As 1 and 7 have sum of 8; it should check once I mean the sum 
SELECT 1122,'1/4/2020',7,'DONE' UNION ALL -- Unfortunately this returns zero as well
SELECT 4466,'1/1/2020',2,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 4466,'1/2/2020',7,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 4466,'1/3/2020',1,'DONE' UNION ALL
SELECT 4466,'1/4/2020',8,'DONE'
),

CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID,
    STOREDATE,
    VALUE,
    CASE 
        WHEN VALUE = 8 THEN 0
        WHEN VALUE + LAG(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY ID, STOREDATE) = 8 
            AND ID = LAG(ID) OVER(ORDER BY ID, STOREDATE) THEN 0
        WHEN VALUE + LEAD(VALUE) OVER(ORDER BY ID, STOREDATE) = 8 
            AND ID = LEAD(ID) OVER(ORDER BY ID, STOREDATE) THEN 0
        ELSE VALUE
    END VALUE2,
    INFO
    FROM your_table
)

SELECT *,
CASE 
    WHEN 
        (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CTE A 
            WHERE A.VALUE2 = 0 AND A.STOREDATE < B.STOREDATE
            AND A.ID = B.ID
        ) >= 1 AND B.VALUE = 8 THEN B.VALUE

    WHEN
        (
            SELECT SUM(A.VALUE) 
            FROM CTE A 
            WHERE A.VALUE2 = 0 
            AND A.STOREDATE < B.STOREDATE
            AND A.ID = B.ID
        )>= 8  THEN B.VALUE

    ELSE B.VALUE2
END VALUE3
FROM CTE B
```

Comment: The above works for multiple ids @mkRabbani. But the expected output isn't returned, see my input samples - Thanks again. Check the input sample that I modified here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=42ae70c1e07ed2280eba8f856eed1604

Comment: Ok i will check.

Comment: @user8512043 please check my updated answer and ref link DEMO2

Comment: Checked already and worked @mkRabbani. Though last two types didn't match. If you can, check my updated post with **Update 1** samples. Thanks again for your time and effort.

Comment: Not sure which sample data set you are indicating to :(

Comment: Please check my question at the end given few input and output sample @mkRabbani.

Comment: OK @mkRabbani. I appreciate your time and thanks very much. If possible, let me know if you can provide any solution later.